# Constant Expression in Linq to SQL is not correctly compiled

Tags: sql, linq, expression, constant-expression

I have two table (mysql) with master-detail relationship that I want to query in Linq (and then experiment it in LinqPad). The problem is Linq to SQL can't produce the correct result nor SQL statement for the following query

```
from m in masters
select new {
   m.Code,
   m.Total,
   Value = m.details.Sum(d => d.Qty * d.Price * (1 - 6/100))
}
```

and another one

```
from m in masters
select new {
   m.Code,
   m.Total,
   Value = m.details.Sum(d => d.Qty * d.Price * 0.94)
}
```

the first query will not produce the correct result as the latter, the problem after I check in LinqPad lies within the `(1 - 6/100)` that compiled into `1.0`. Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first expression uses integer math and thus is correct, just not what you expected. You've assumed that C# will infer floating point semantics from integer literals. The second expression is a simply a double literal.

In integer math, `6/100` is 0, so `(1 - 6/100)` is 1. You need to *coerce* the division expression into using double values by making the numerator or denominator a double literal.

Instead try:

```
Value = m.details.Sum(d => d.Qty * d.Price * (1 - 6/100.0))
```

Note the `.0` to make that a double expression.

Comment: Ooh that's right, I completely forgot about that. Thanks a lot.